# PHP Regex getting data from String and into array

Tags: php, regex

I have the following data

```
<terminal:Text>1  #VS   5 J9 C9 D9 I9 Z9 W9 S9 H9 LHRMIA 1235 1705      744 0E</terminal:Text>
<terminal:Text>2  #IB4637 F9 A9 J9 C9 D9 R9 I. W9 LHRMIA 1415 1825   *  744 0E</terminal:Text>
<terminal:Text>3*O#AA  57 F7 A7 P7 J7 R7 D7 I7 Y7 LHRMIA 0945 1415      777 0E</terminal:Text>
```

I have now successfully obtained the flight numbers which start with a # and contain 2 uppercase letters and 1-4 digits e.g. (VS5).  To do this I have done

```
while ($elNum < $elements->length) {

    $flightInfo = $elements->item($elNum)->nodeValue;

    if(preg_match('/\d+[^#]*\#(\p{Lu}{2})\s*(\d{1,4})\b/', $flightInfo, $matches ) === 1){
        $fltCode = $matches[0];

        $this->flights[] = array(
            "flightNumber" => $fltCode
        );
    }

    ++$elNum;
}
```

$elements represents a  element, so I am looping each one of these, finding the rows that start with a digit, and then extracting the flight numbers into my array.

Now I need to get all the seat/availability which are the letter/number combinations which come after the flight numbers e.g. J9, C9, D9 etc.

So $flightInfo contains all the data for a row.  Now really, I am thinking that now I have all the flight numbers I should strip them from the $flightInfo String?

My main question is how I can get the seat/availability for each row into my flights array?  Should I do another if statement?  My only problem is that there might be another letter/number combination in the String which may not relate to this part.  What I know is that the ones I need come after the flight number and before the six uppercase letters e.g. LHRMIA.

Any advice on the best way to handle this appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need **lookahead** based regex to solve this task

Comment: Why do you  need regex?  It looks like to you have space- or tab-separated values that you should be able to work with in a more structured manner.

Comment: initially I was just exploding the whole row of data but this was getting quite complicated to handle.  Do you think I should go back to exploding on spaces and sorting it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `\K` operator with Perl/PCRE regex and a positive look-ahead to check for exactly 6 uppercase letter:

```
$re = "/\\d+[^#]*\\#\\p{Lu}{2}\\s*\\d{1,4}\\b\\s*\\K[\\w ]+(?=\\s+\\p{Lu}{6})/";
```

[This will return](https://regex101.com/r/uC8cL8/1) `J9 C9 D9 I9 Z9 W9 S9 H9` as an entire match, and just split with space.

Sample code:

```
$subject = "<terminal:Text>1  #VS   5 J9 C9 D9 I9 Z9 W9 S9 H9 LHRMIA 1235 1705      744 0E</terminal:Text>"; 
$pattern = '/\\d+[^#]*\\#\\p{Lu}{2}\\s*\\d{1,4}\\b\\s*\\K[\\w ]+(?=\\s+\\p{Lu}{6})/'; 
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches); 
$arrayOfSeats = explode(" ", $matches[0]);
  print_r($arrayOfSeats);
```

[Output](https://ideone.com/tr8Wsd):

```
Array
(
    [0] => J9
    [1] => C9
    [2] => D9
    [3] => I9
    [4] => Z9
    [5] => W9
    [6] => S9
    [7] => H9
)
```

**EDIT:**

On second thought, I think you can even initialize all the arrays with [1 regex](https://regex101.com/r/uC8cL8/2):

`(?<=<terminal:Text>)\d+[^#]*?\#(\p{Lu}{2})\s*(\d{1,4})\b\s*([\w. ]+?)(?=\s+\p{Lu}{6})`

You will have to combine the 1st and 2nd groups of each match to get flight numbers, and then the 3rd group should be split into an array to obtain the seat array. So, you won't have to run the same regex twice.

Output:

```
Match 1:
 Group1: VS
 Group2: 5
 Group3: J9 C9 D9 I9 Z9 W9 S9 H9
Match 2:
 Group1: IB
 Group2: 4637
 Group3: F9 A9 J9 C9 D9 R9 I. W9
Match 3:
 Group1: AA
 Group2: 57
 Group3: F7 A7 P7 J7 R7 D7 I7 Y7
```